# Jenkins remote executors are disconnecting frequently

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am trying to setup 4 RHEL machines in jenkins as build executors. But the systems are getting disconnected so frequently. I have checked the following points already. Still no luck

1. Network problems between master and slave
2. Slave server availability
3. Slow response from slave (disabled Response time in Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > Configure > Response time)

I am getting the following error everytime

```
Feb 22, 2019 7:59:55 PM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
INFO: I/O error in channel channel
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:77)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
        at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:49)
        at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:140)
        at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:126)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:36)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
```

Comment: yes, it disconnects frequently on mac machines; I wonder whether there is some infrastructure to get system event for disconnection, at least...

Comment: actually there is this one: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mail+Watcher+Plugin